# Global variable in a module not accessible after the module being imported

Tags: rascal

I found that in the Rascal console, after I import a module which contains global variable definitions, these global variables are not accessible.  Only global function names are accessible.  For example, in the following code, after I import `Foo` in the console, I can call `x()` to get `1`, but dereference `x` gives me an unbound variable error.  Why?

```
module Foo

int x = 1;

int x() = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globals are default `private` in Rascal, to prevent you from easily doing such nastiness :-)

```
module Foo

public int x = 1;

int x() = 1;
```

This is a bit inconsistent, since the function is `public` by default but not when you consider that we will eventually remove globals from the language :-)

Comment: Completely removing global variables sounds reasonable.  But it would be nice to have the possibility to define global constants.

Comment: agreed, globals constants are harmless and useful